# wordpress url issue html multiple

Tags: html, wordpress, url

I have one big problem. I have installed the latest version (4.1.1)of wordpress locally(wamp) in the folder www. I wanted to change my html site's url. I changed my wordpress url and site url from settings -> general with the same name  as this locally/wordpress/revenant. When I saved changes, a 'not found' page appeard with error "The requested URL /wordpress/revenant/wp-login.php was not found on this server". Revenant is an HTML site I created. I put this site in wp-content/themes, a folder with the name revenant which has footer.php, header.php, index.php and style.css in it. My first question is how am I going to retrieve and see my dashboard, admin page and second how to load multiple HTML sites with different url's? To manage my site (go to the about-contact page, nav menu ec) in which parts do I have to change my HTML code to PHP? I am a junior developer and need help. And why in settings->reading didn't appear the choice of front page displays? I want to check as ' a static page ' and I can not. Thank you in advance. If you want any code let me know.

Comment: rewrite module is enabled in wamp ? have you checked if the site is working properly with default url option ?

Comment: yes Shah Rukh i forgot to tell it.my site was working before.For rewrite module do you mean i have to go to apache and to httpd.conf file and delete the hash( # )symbol?no i havent done it. i have  to see the admin page first!

Comment: yup you have to do that remove hash